# Divide patients into 2 groups

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, t-test, differences

Study design: pre-test (questionnaire) treatment post-test (same questionnaire as in pre). A higher questionnaire score in the post compared to the pre indicated a successful treatment effect.
Like in a t-Test I want to compare significant differences between pre and post scores (if the treatment had an effect) but not on group level but on individual level. Meaning did the treatment had a positive effect on the socre of the participant.
How do I calculate the significant difference of post-pre for each participant separatly? Is there a statistical test? Apparently I can't use the t-Test because this one is based on group level but I want to test for individual differences. Because I want to classificate the subjects into "the treatment has an effect on the participant" and "the treatment has no effect on the participant".

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described it's not possible to "calculate the significant difference of post-pre for each participant separately" because you only have 1 post-pre score for each patient.  Even if you had multiple pre-post scores for each patient you would still have to account for their lack of independence.

However, you could conduct a paired t-test.  It would test whether the population of post-pre differences is significantly different from 0.  As you mention, the inference for this would be on the group as a whole and not on any particular individual.

Answer (score 0):

You can test at the Individual level if you know the standard error of measurement. Here are some sources:

Christensen, L., & Mendoza, J. L. (1986). A method of assessing change
in a single subject: An alteration of the RC index. Behavior Therapy,
17, 305–308.

Hageman, W. L., & Arrindell, W. A. (1993). A further refinement of
the reliable change index by improving the pre–post difference score: Introducing the RCID. Behaviour Research and Therapy, 51, 693–700.